# Inline If statement - short-circuiting

Tags: c#, if-statement, inline, short-circuiting

As I understand and read you can use short circuiting in if statement (&& or ||) in order for second condition not to fire. and if you want both condition to fire you would use single operands (& or |).

So say if I have inline if statement as below :

```
var test = (MyObject != null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(MyObject.Property)) ? string.Empty : MyObject.Property;
```

This will throw `object reference` error if MyObject is null, which in my opinion should not as I am using short circuiting. Can someone please explain this.

Comment: You're missing a closing parenthesis before the '?'.

Comment: @Corak yes missed the last bracket...edited now

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're using the wrong condition. This part:

```
MyObject != null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(MyObject.Property)
```

should be:

```
MyObject == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(MyObject.Property)
```

The RHS of an `||` only executes if the left hand is *false*. You want it to only execute if `MyObject` is *not* null.

EDIT: If you really want the `MyObject != null` part, you could change the whole thing to:

```
var test = MyObject != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(MyObject.Property)
       ? MyObject.Property : "";
```

Note the reversal of the 2nd and 3rd operands of the conditional operator too though.

Comment: ah i see so if I do && for same condition instead of || it should be fine

Comment: @Sam1: Well you'd need to reverse other bits of it as well.

Answer (score 3):

You should have an == not an !=

```
var test = (MyObject == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(MyObject.Property) ? string.Empty : MyObject.Property
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var test = (MyObject == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(MyObject.Property)
             ? string.Empty : MyObject.Property
```

Answer (score 2):

```
MyObject != null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(MyObject.Property)
```

Here you say.

If my object is not null.
or 
string.IsNullOrEmpty(MyObject.Property)

Which means that if MyObject is null he will try to execute the second part.

```
MyObject == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(MyObject.Property)
```

This won't throw null exception

Answer (score 2):

That happens because `MyObject` is `null` and therefore the first condition is `false` so the second part must be evaluated to know the whole of the condition. Change the line to this:

```
MyObject != null && string.IsNullOrEmpty(MyObject.Property)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should prefer readability instead of line-count, e.g.:

```
string prop = string.Empty;
if(MyObject != null && MyObject.Property != null)
    prop = MyObject.Property;
```

(the reason for your exception was already explained in other answers)

Comment: line count isn't always the goal. For example, within a Lamda/predicate, forcing the use of `{` & `}` and also an explicit return can be just as unreadable.